# How to do string attachment with wp_mail

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, attachments, wp-mail, pdf

I'm using a gift card plugin for my woocommerce shop and I would like to add a generated pdf file to allow customers to download the gift card as a pdf.

The idea is to use TCpdf or Fpdf to generate the pdf and output it as a string.

```
// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.


echo $pdf->Output('S');
```

The problem is to get this file as an attachment with wp_mail. Right now, I have this code from the plugin, and i don't know how to call the pdf :

```
/**
 * Hooks before the email is sent
 *
 * @since 2.1
 */
do_action( 'kodiak_email_send_before', $this );

$subject = $this->parse_tags( $subject );
$message = $this->parse_tags( $message );
$message = $this->build_email( $message );

$attachments = ??;


$sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $this->get_headers(), $attachments );
$log_errors = apply_filters( 'kodiak_log_email_errors', true, $to, $subject, $message );

if( ! $sent && true === $log_errors ) {
  if ( is_array( $to ) ) {
    $to = implode( ',', $to );
  }

  $log_message = sprintf(
    __( "Email from Gift Cards failed to send.\nSend time: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n", 'kodiak-giftcards' ),
    date_i18n( 'F j Y H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
    $to,
    $subject
  );
}
```

Is someone can help me with this ?

Thank you for the answer !

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add an attachment using the standard 'wp_mail' function, however you would need to hook into the `phpmailer_init` action to do so.

Because this will require calling another function where you don't have any context, you may need to register the action function anonymously with the `use ( $attachments )` statement, store the attachment content as a global variable or property, or place the attachment generation code into the new function.

I can see that OP's code seems to be in the context of a class method, so I'll try to create an example which should be compatible / consistent.

```
    // Previous Code...
    
    // Use this action to generate and/or attach files.
    add_filter( 'phpmailer_init', array( $this, 'add_attachments' ) );
    // And/or store the attachments as a property.
    $this->set_attachments( $attachments );
    
    $sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $this->get_headers() );

    // Log errors etc...
    if ( ! $sent ) {
        //...
        $this->log_error( $error_message );
    }
}

/**
 * Add attachments to the email.
 *
 * This method must be public in order to work as an action.
 * @param PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer $phpmailer
 */
public function add_attachments( $phpmailer ) {
    // Remove filter to prevent attaching the files to subsequent emails.
    remove_action( 'phpmailer_init', array( $this, 'add_attachments' ) );
    // Get or generate the attachments somehow.
    foreach ( $this->get_attachments() as $filename, $file_contents ) {
        try {
            $phpmailer->addStringAttachment( $file_contents, $filename );
        } catch( \Exception $ex ) {
            // An exception may thrown which would prevent the remaining files from being attached, so we'll catch these and log the errors.
            // This email may be sent without attachments. Do not try/catch if you don't want the email to be sent without all the attachments.
            $this->log_error( $ex->getMessage() );
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Abstraction for the logging code to make it reusable.
 * @param string $log_message
 */
protected function log_error( $log_message ) {
    if ( ! $this->log_errors ) {
        return;
    }
    // Log errors here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of tricky to do, but it is possible. Write a class which will extend `PHPMailer`. Override the `addAttachment` method, so in a certain condition (ex. you make a Boolean class variable) it will call `addStringAttachment` from the original class and in every other cases the `addAttachment` class. All you have to do is to set

`$attachment = array("your content goes here");`

When this is done, make sure that the global `$phpmailer` variable is an instance of your class and then create the specific condition. `wp_mail` will call the `addAttachment` from your class, and together with your special condition the attachment will be sent without saving the file.

Answer (score -1):

Usually I proceed like this

```
$attachment = array(filepath);
```

Where filepath is the path to your file.

Comment: The author is asking to add attachments by string, not from a file path.